# Trying to create a new table based off union all from multiple tables but get incorrect syntax near '(' expecting ')' or SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is create a new table based off the union of all the other tables(16 in total) since they have the same columns. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

```
select * into NewTable from(
  select *
  from table 1 
  union all

  select *
  from table 2 
  union all
) as sub

...
```

I keep getting incorrect syntax near '(' expecting ')' or SELECT. Am I suppose to give an alias to each table within the sub query? Not sure what to do.

Comment: Please tag appropriately.  MySQL <> SQL Server.  But that 2nd `UNION ALL` line is what's causing your issue in either case.

Comment: Agreed... we need to know the vendor/version of your SQL Server

Comment: The ol' debugging trick: what happens when you execute _just the part_ inside `from()`? If you copy and paste that to a new window the syntax error might be more visually obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an extra `Union All` statement at the end of your query.

Please try:

```
select * into NewTable from(
select *
from table 1 
union all

(select *
from table 2 )
Union ALL

(Select Field1, Field 2
 from Table3 )
) as sub
```

Depending on the size of your tables, you might want to limit the columns returned instead of selecting all of them.

Comment: How would you do this to union all more than two tables?

Comment: @GeorgeZambrano I suggest using Union All ( Select Field1, Field2 from Table3)  That is, add this logic to the line above your closing parenthesis and sub alias.  Please see edited response.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I went to figure this out for MS SQL, which I don't usually use, just for fun.

Here is a [complete example from SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/966640/1/0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (col_1 int);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (col_1 int);

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (100), (200);

SELECT * INTO union_table 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1) AS X UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM table_2);

SELECT * FROM union_table;
```

Returns:

| col_1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 100 |
| 200 |